# time4j is not producing monotonic time in long since epoch

Tags: java, time4j

I'm trying to produce monotonic time in long since epoch using time4j v5.6 using below test code

But output is not expected. Did I miss any initialization of the library? My objective is to produce monotonic time but don't need high precision as this can be executed on client side either linux/windows

```
import net.time4j.SystemClock;

import java.time.Instant;

public class MonotonicClock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SystemClock systemClock = SystemClock.MONOTONIC;
        long t1 = systemClock.currentTimeInMicros() * 1000;
        boolean failed = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000_000; i++) {
            long t2 = systemClock.currentTimeInMicros() * 1000;
            if (t2 < t1) {
                System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, t2) + "<" + Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, t1));
                failed = true;
            }
            t1 = t2;
        }

        if(failed) {
            System.err.println("Test Failed");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Test Passed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting and what are you expectations?

Comment: "Test Failed" output. I expected lib produce long timestamp which is same or greater than previous timestamp

Comment: Why are you multiplying the time in microseconds by 1000?

Comment: Multiplying is not necessary. just to view timestamp output from Instant, may be there is a better for it

Comment: Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, t2) - second param is adjustment in nanos and can be full timestamp in nanos. that's ok. you may run sample class above and verify

Answer (score 2):

The Clock `SystemClock.MONOTONIC` is ultimately based on `System.nanoTime()`, see the [source code](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/a1c03133c61ed192e782eb1f108d6eed040d07d7/base/src/main/java/net/time4j/SystemClock.java#L484). Latter one **should be** monotonic, and at least the handling of rare leap seconds is safely monotonic here, but it might happen to be not monotonic on some multi-core platforms where the JVM has difficulties to switch between the cores to form a consistent result of calling `System.nanoTime()`. See also the [related SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854104/2491410) with more useful links to the debate about the monotonicity of `System.nanoTime()`.

A workaround could be to introduce a new constant `SystemClock.MONOTONIC_ENFORCED` which deploys a CAS-algorithm (based on `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong`) to compare the actual nano-time with the previous one (with possible performance penalty). Let me know if you need this feature in the next release of Time4J.

Comment: Thanks for all the information in the post. If this doesn't penalize with lot of CPU cycles then it might be a worthy addition in the library. This will be useful in instances where events needs sequencing by time