# Why Thread.sleep(long mills, int nanos) and Object.wait(long mills, int nanos) actually ignore nanoseconds amount (according to their source code)?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using JDK 17 on macOS.
I looked into `Thread.sleep(long mills, int nanos)` and `Object.wait(long mills, int nanos)` and their source code as follows:

Thread.sleep:

```
    public static void sleep(long millis, int nanos)
    throws InterruptedException {
        if (millis < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
        }

        if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
        }

        if (nanos > 0 && millis < Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            millis++;
        }

        sleep(millis);
    }
```

Object.wait:

```
    public final void wait(long timeoutMillis, int nanos) throws InterruptedException {
        if (timeoutMillis < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeoutMillis value is negative");
        }

        if (nanos < 0 || nanos > 999999) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                "nanosecond timeout value out of range");
        }

        if (nanos > 0 && timeoutMillis < Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            timeoutMillis++;
        }

        wait(timeoutMillis);
    }
```

So according to code nanos amount is actually ignored -if it is more than zero, then mills will just increment.
Why is that?
Is it because my system does not support nanos resolution?

Comment: TLDR: [Javadoc for `sleep`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~iris/se/17/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long,int)) says, "...subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers." They're future-proofing the API by allowing you to specify time down to the nanosecond, but they're also allowing present-day implementations to be less accurate.

Comment: If you need high-precision timing, then you should be using a [real-time edition of Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java), running on some [real-time OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) of `System#nanoTime`:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of `currentTimeMillis()`

All of this to say is that while `System#nanoTime` will provide you a time in nanoseconds, it will not necessarily be an *accurate* time. Rather, the time will only be at least as accurate as `System#currentTimeMillis`. Due to this, there has been a history of `System#nanoTime` occasionally returning erroneous values on successive calls (such as [returning a *lower* value than a previous result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854104/1786065)).

To that end, it is simpler to increment the number of required milliseconds to ensure that the duration waited surpasses the number of desired nanoseconds, rather than to actually check against `System#nanoTime`.

It is also noted within the javadoc for [Object#wait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,%20int)):

> nanos - additional time, in nanoseconds range 0-999999.

and [Thread#sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long,%20int)):

> nanos - 0-999999 additional nanoseconds to sleep

Such that the number of nanoseconds cannot exceed an additional millisecond, allowing them to simply increment the milliseconds by 1 in the event additional nanoseconds must be waited for.

Answer (score 0):

Use LockSupport.parkNanos instead. Under Linux this will give you 50us resolution. https://hazelcast.com/blog/locksupport-parknanos-under-the-hood-and-the-curious-case-of-parking/